# Homestead не добавляется в PATH

Tags: laravel, homestead

Здравствуйте. Выполняю комманду:

```
composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"
```

Получаю результат:

```
Changed current directory to /home/dualse/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

Далее вывоже содержимое переменное $PATH, но там отсутствует

> ~/.composer/vendor/bin

Можно ли это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте строчку

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

в `~/.bashrc`. Начиная со следующего логина (или с выполнения `source ~/.bashrc`) $PATH должен будет содержать вышеприведенный путь.